# @KafkaListener better solution to consume one million plus messages a day?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a spring KafkaListener in a spring boot project:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-one", groupId = "groupone")
public void listen(CustomerDetails customerDetails) {
    if(customerDetails.getCertainDetails!= null && !customerDetails.getCertainDetails.isEmpty()) {
        dbInsert;
} else {
 log.info(customerDetails.toString)
```

}
}

This listener will be receiving one million plus messages a day.
How do i ensure that i dont run into concurrency issue while too many messages are coming in and db insertion? Or i do not need to worry about it?
Is there a better solution for the above code approach?

Comment: If you've got data in a Kafka topic to write to a database you should be using Kafka Connect e.g. https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video

Answer (score 1):

> How do i ensure that i dont run into concurrency issue while too many messages are coming in and db insertion

Unless your databse client runs asynchronously, you likely would not run into that problem. The KafkaListener is blocking, and you configure your own `max.poll.records` setting in Kafka consumer properties to handle the backpressure; you would never be adding more records than that at once.

Are you currently seeing anything that indicates that would be the fact?

> Is there a better solution

In general, yes. It requires you to not manage Kafka Consumers on your own and use a [Kafka Connect sink](http://www.confluent.io/hub/) for your respective database.